# How to filter the access to path with gtk.fileselection (python)?

Tags: python, file, path, pygtk

I working with gtk.fileselection and it works perfectly. But how can I block the access to a given path with fileselection widget.
If I do not block access to a certain path, the user can see sensitive information inside my system.

```
class FileSelection:
# Get the selected filename and print it to the console
def file_ok_sel(self, w):
    print "%s" % self.filew.get_filename()

def destroy(self, widget):
    gtk.main_quit()

def __init__(self):
    #Create a new file selection widget
    self.filew = gtk.FileSelection("File selection")
    self.filew.hide_fileop_buttons()
    self.filew.get_focus()


    self.filew.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
    # Connect the ok_button to file_ok_sel method
    self.filew.ok_button.connect("clicked", self.file_ok_sel)

    # Connect the cancel_button to destroy the widget
    self.filew.cancel_button.connect("clicked",lambda w: self.filew.destroy())

    # Lets set the filename, as if this were a save dialog,
    # and we are giving a default filename
    self.filew.set_filename("penguin.png")

    self.filew.show()

def main(self):
    gtk.main()
    print "selection"*10
    return 0
```

In fact I would like to allow access only to the paths that hang from "mnt/tnc/" and not allow access to any more.

Comment: The `Gtk.FileChooser` has the option to use a `Gtk.FileFilter`. However, you should note that a filter does not imply that your program is secured from accessing other folders. For that you would need it to drop privileges. To sandbox your application like that, you could try to use [Flatpak](http://flatpak.org/) for example.

Comment: Thank you @elya5 but I solve this listing the files in the folder I want. Then I show the list in a new window, with a button each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 archivosTNC = os.listdir("/mnt/tnc")
    lista = []     
    for a in archivosTNC:
        if a[-2:] == ".H":
            lista.append(a)
        elif a[-4:] == ".txt":
            lista.append(a)
        elif a[-4:] == ".png":
            lista.append(a)
        elif a[-4:] == ".jpg":
            lista.append(a) 

    ventana = gtk.Window()
    ventana.set_default_size(-1, 300)
    scrolledWindow = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolledWindow.set_policy (hscrollbar_policy=gtk.POLICY_NEVER, vscrollbar_policy=gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    ventana.add(scrolledWindow)
    tabla=table()
    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    tabla.attachToCell(vbox, col=1, row=1)
    scrolledWindow.add_with_viewport(tabla)

    #ventana.add(vbox)
    for item in lista:
        boton = gtk.Button(str(item))
        boton.connect('clicked', self.devolverNombreArchivo)
        vbox.pack_start(boton)
```